# jQuery Script is not working after Pagination

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am using the [Divi Blog Extension](https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/divi-resources/free-divi-extension-gives-the-divi-blog-module-a-brand-new-look) which gives their old Blog Grid Module a new look. 
[This is the github repository](https://github.com/andyhqtran/divi-100-article-card) of it.

So, if I enable the extension on WordPress, this **changes the look** of the 1st 6 blogs on grid that are **on the 1st page** of the pagination. 
But whenever I click on 2,3,4 or any other page of the **pagination**, the next 6 blogs load but the script of that extension **doesn't apply** the style to those blogs.

**How can I make this script this work after every pagination loads so that new blog grid get the same style change as well?**

This is the `scripts.js` code of that extension below.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
   if (!$('.divi-100-article-card').length) {
     return false;
   } else {
     $('.et_pb_blog_grid').find('.et_pb_post').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);

 /**
  * Adds article-card class to div
 */
  $this
    .addClass('article-card');

  /**
   * Creates content div and appends to post
   */
  $this
    .append('<div class="article-card__content" />');

  /**
   * Post variables
   */
  var postContent = $this.find('.article-card__content');
  var postMeta = $this.children('.post-meta');

  /**
   * Excerpt variables
   */
  var excerpt = $this.clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
  var excerptWrap = $('<div class="article-card__excerpt" />');

  if ($this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').length > 0) {
    excerpt = $this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').text();
    $this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').remove();
  }

  /**
   * Check if excerpt is over 100 characters
   */
  if (excerpt.length > 80) {
    excerpt = excerpt.substring(0, 80).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "..."
  }

  /**
   * Creates category div based off post-meta children
   */
  postMeta
    .children('a')
    .addClass('article-card__category')
    .appendTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Appends excerpt to content div
   */
  excerptWrap
    .text(excerpt)
    .appendTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Creates meta div and appends to content
   */
  postContent
    .append('<div class="article-card__meta" />');

  /**
   * Removes old text from post
   */
  $this
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
      return (this.nodeType == 3);
    })
    .remove();

  /**
   * Creates date div based off .published
   */
  $(this).find('.published').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().slice(0, -6);
  });

  $this
    .find('.published')
    .appendTo(this)
    .replaceWith(function (i, text) {
      return (
        text
          .replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)([\d\D]*)/g,
            '<div class="article-card__date">\
              <span class="article-card__day">$2</span>\
              <span class="article-card__month">$1</span>\
            </div>'
          )
      );
    });

  /**
   * Removes comma, spaces from day
   */
  $this
    .find('.article-card__day')
    .text(function () {
      return $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(/\,/g, '')
        .trim();
    });

  /**
   * Add article-card__title class to title
   */
  $this
    .find('.entry-title')
    .addClass('article-card__title')
    .prependTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Appends author to content div
   */
  $this
    .find('.author')
    .addClass('article-card__author')
    .appendTo($this.find('.article-card__meta'));


  /**
   * Get existing comment and appends it to post comment
   */
  var comments = postMeta.text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").replace("by", "").trim();

  if (comments) {
    $('<span class="article-card__comments">' + comments + '</span>')
      .appendTo($this.find('.article-card__meta'));
  }

  /**
   * Remove old post-meta div
   */
  postMeta.remove();

  /**
   * If .post-content exist, then append contents to excerpt
   */
  if ($(this).find('.post-content').length > 0) {
    $(this)
      .find('.post-content p')
      .appendTo($(this)
        .find('.article-card__excerpt'));
  }

  /**
   * Hide excerpt by default on desktop
   */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $this
      .children()
      .children('.article-card__excerpt')
      .hide();
  }

  /**
   * Get outer height of content div and applies a padding to card
   */
  function postModuleSize() {
    var postContentHeight = postContent.outerHeight();

    $this.css({
      'padding-bottom': postContentHeight
    });
  }

  setTimeout(postModuleSize, 100);

  /**
   * Recall getPostContentSize() on window resize
   */
  $(window).resize(function () {
    postModuleSize();
  });

  /**
   * Handle animations on desktop
   */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {

    /**
     * Prevents loading incorrect state
     */
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.on('hover', function () {
        $this.find('.article-card__excerpt').stop().animate({
          height: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
         });
        });
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Page URL doesn't change. It remains same. But all the blog grids are there. So I added a pagination under 1st 6 blogs. 

When I click on the 2 no page, the next 6 blog loads but the Page URL is same.

Comment: Okay, but how can I do that? What code to add in this script file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The script you've posted is executed only on page load `jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { /* ... */ })`

you can may transform the script in this way:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
    // call the function
    myDiviScript();

})

// wrap the cod inside a function
function myDiviScript() {
   if (!$('.divi-100-article-card').length) {
     return false;
   } else {
     $('.et_pb_blog_grid').find('.et_pb_post').each(function () {
       var $this = $(this);

 /**
  * Adds article-card class to div
 */
  $this
    .addClass('article-card');

  /**
   * Creates content div and appends to post
   */
  $this
    .append('<div class="article-card__content" />');

  /**
   * Post variables
   */
  var postContent = $this.find('.article-card__content');
  var postMeta = $this.children('.post-meta');

  /**
   * Excerpt variables
   */
  var excerpt = $this.clone().children().remove().end().text().trim();
  var excerptWrap = $('<div class="article-card__excerpt" />');

  if ($this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').length > 0) {
    excerpt = $this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').text();
    $this.children('p').not('p.post-meta').remove();
  }

  /**
   * Check if excerpt is over 100 characters
   */
  if (excerpt.length > 80) {
    excerpt = excerpt.substring(0, 80).split(" ").slice(0, -1).join(" ") + "..."
  }

  /**
   * Creates category div based off post-meta children
   */
  postMeta
    .children('a')
    .addClass('article-card__category')
    .appendTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Appends excerpt to content div
   */
  excerptWrap
    .text(excerpt)
    .appendTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Creates meta div and appends to content
   */
  postContent
    .append('<div class="article-card__meta" />');

  /**
   * Removes old text from post
   */
  $this
    .contents()
    .filter(function () {
      return (this.nodeType == 3);
    })
    .remove();

  /**
   * Creates date div based off .published
   */
  $(this).find('.published').text(function () {
    return $(this).text().slice(0, -6);
  });

  $this
    .find('.published')
    .appendTo(this)
    .replaceWith(function (i, text) {
      return (
        text
          .replace(/([a-zA-Z]+)([\d\D]*)/g,
            '<div class="article-card__date">\
              <span class="article-card__day">$2</span>\
              <span class="article-card__month">$1</span>\
            </div>'
          )
      );
    });

  /**
   * Removes comma, spaces from day
   */
  $this
    .find('.article-card__day')
    .text(function () {
      return $(this)
        .text()
        .replace(/\,/g, '')
        .trim();
    });

  /**
   * Add article-card__title class to title
   */
  $this
    .find('.entry-title')
    .addClass('article-card__title')
    .prependTo(postContent);

  /**
   * Appends author to content div
   */
  $this
    .find('.author')
    .addClass('article-card__author')
    .appendTo($this.find('.article-card__meta'));


  /**
   * Get existing comment and appends it to post comment
   */
  var comments = postMeta.text().replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9 ]/g, "").replace("by", "").trim();

  if (comments) {
    $('<span class="article-card__comments">' + comments + '</span>')
      .appendTo($this.find('.article-card__meta'));
  }

  /**
   * Remove old post-meta div
   */
  postMeta.remove();

  /**
   * If .post-content exist, then append contents to excerpt
   */
  if ($(this).find('.post-content').length > 0) {
    $(this)
      .find('.post-content p')
      .appendTo($(this)
        .find('.article-card__excerpt'));
  }

  /**
   * Hide excerpt by default on desktop
   */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {
    $this
      .children()
      .children('.article-card__excerpt')
      .hide();
  }

  /**
   * Get outer height of content div and applies a padding to card
   */
  function postModuleSize() {
    var postContentHeight = postContent.outerHeight();

    $this.css({
      'padding-bottom': postContentHeight
    });
  }

  setTimeout(postModuleSize, 100);

  /**
   * Recall getPostContentSize() on window resize
   */
  $(window).resize(function () {
    postModuleSize();
  });

  /**
   * Handle animations on desktop
   */
  if ($(window).width() > 768) {

    /**
     * Prevents loading incorrect state
     */
    setTimeout(function () {
      $this.on('hover', function () {
        $this.find('.article-card__excerpt').stop().animate({
          height: "toggle",
          opacity: "toggle"
        }, 200);
         });
        });
      }
    });
  }
};
```

Test if the scripts working as normal, if yes you need to call `myDiviScript()` in the callback of your pagination script.

If you have difficult to attach to the callback you can also try this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  myDiviScript()
});
```

This attach the function to the end of every ajax call, a better way is this:

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function( event, xhr, settings ) {
  if ( settings.url === "YOURREQEUSTURL" ) {
    myDiviScript()
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm trying this and will let you know.