# jQuery script not working after page is refreshed using pagination or Ajax in WooCommerce

Tags: jquery, ajax, woocommerce

I have written a script to add a mouseover effect on the product archives of my Woocommerce Eshop page.
The script works fine when the page is initially loaded.
My problem is that when i click Pagination page 2,3,.. or use any Ajax filters the effect is lost.
I have found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57268300/jquery-script-is-not-working-after-pagination) that explains that the

```
ready(function)
```

works on page load only, but i am not sure how to make it work on my case.
I am adding this script on the head of my WP website.

```
<script>
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {

///archive page mouseover 
jQuery("li.product-type-simple").mouseover(function(){
jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 10px 46px #7a7b7c");
 });
jQuery("li.product-type-simple").mouseout(function(){
jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "unset");
 });
    
jQuery("li.product-type-variable").mouseover(function(){
jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 10px 46px #7a7b7c");
 });
jQuery("li.product-type-variable").mouseout(function(){
jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "unset");
});



});
</script>
```

I need to make the above script work not only when hitting the refresh button but also when using Ajax functionalities like Ajax filters or Woo Commerce pagination.

Comment: Could'nt you simply overwrite the CSS instead ? Add `li.product-type-simple:hover{box-shadow: 5px 10px 46px #7a7b7c;}` to your custom css Sytelesheet. I dont really see the need to, nor advantage in using JS here.

Comment: You're right, started this for some other interaction that i eventually removed and then i got lost why this is not working. Thanks for the clear mind!

Answer (score 2):

Please use below script. You've to use following convention to trigger any event on dynamically rendered elements. Thanks :)

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function() {
   jQuery(document).on("mouseover", "li.product-type-simple", function(){
       jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 10px 46px #7a7b7c");
   });

   jQuery(document).on("mouseout", "li.product-type-simple", function(){
       jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "unset");
   });

   jQuery(document).on("mouseover", "li.product-type-variable", function(){
       jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "5px 10px 46px #7a7b7c");
   });

   jQuery(document).on("mouseout", "li.product-type-variable", function(){
       jQuery(this).css("box-shadow", "unset");
   });

});
```